# How to get an image from video in android

Tags: android

I have a ImageView.
I want to get an image from a video. The image is representation of the video.
The image will be displayed on the ImageView.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337505/android-capture-video-frame

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091794/android-screen-capturing-or-make-video-from-images) could help you.